# Class method on active record that works like scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following two models: User and Cost.
User has_many costs.  Costs define the cost / hour of a user and have a from date field.

I would like to have the possibility to ask the current cost of a user like this:

```
User.last.costs.current
```

To do so I can make this scope in the Cost model:

```
scope :current, -> { where('"from" <= ?', Date.today).order('"costs"."from" desc').limit(1) }
```

This works but will require this syntax:

```
User.last.costs.current.first
```

Which I personally don't like.

I believe there are several options to solve this:

1) Add a method to the User model which would get the current cost.

2) Add a class method to Cost which would get the current cost.  However this would result in the following syntax to get a current cost:

```
 Cost.get_current_cost_by_user(User.last)
```

So finally my question: Is it possible to create a class method on the Cost model that would allow me to do:

```
User.last.costs.current
```

And return the current cost?

If it's not possible what would be best practise to implement this: method on User model or class method on Cost that requires user as parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this which works like `User.last.costs.current # => Cost`. The problem is that this also can be called like `Cost.current`, which wouldn't make much sense.

```
class Cost < AR
  def self.current
    where('"from" <= ?', Date.today).order('"costs"."from" desc').first
  end
end
```

Comment: You are totally right.  Side question : How does the class method know of the user?

Comment: Rails creates an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object under the hood and passes it around. I'm not sure about the details, but take a look at [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) for more info.

Comment: You would have to either use `belongs_to :user` or pass the current_user to the class method.

Comment: @max I think is enough if the user has `has_many :costs` for it to work.